# Google script sidebar buttons don't work for other users

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

We have created sidebar for Google sheets and added few buttons to format data easily. But the problem is, these buttons work for the one who created the sidebar. For all other users they do nothing and functions don't get called. Functions themselves are fully tested and they work well. Seems like other users just can't call them on button click.

This is the code for sidebar (The functions are located in separate `final.gs` file):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <base target="_top">
</head>
<body>

  <button id="clean" >Clean Up Data</button><br>
  <button id="categories" >Style Categories</button><br>
  <button id="test" >Run All </button><br>
  <button id="delete" >Delete All </button><br>

  <script>
         document.getElementById("test").addEventListener("click", function(){
             google.script.run.call_all_funcions();
         });

         document.getElementById("clean").addEventListener("click", function(){
             google.script.run.cleanUpData();
         });

         document.getElementById("categories").addEventListener("click", function(){
             google.script.run.style_categories_WithBorders();
         });

         document.getElementById("delete").addEventListener("click", function(){
             google.script.run.clearSheet();
         });
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

What are we doing wrong? Or maybe there are some kind of permissions?

Comment: Add success and failure handlers

Answer (score 0):

I tried to debug and returned error message. Turned out it was permission issues. The solution was to simply sign out of all Google accounts and then sign in with only the one that has permissions to edit the file. Now everything works.